# Jenkins Multi-Branch role based security

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to setup/configure Jenkins/Jenkinsfile to permit only specific users/roles to interact with user input dialog boxes?

Conceptually in my head I see the workflow as a single job that all users can see. But prevent developers from pushing a release into production by restricting which users can click 'yes' on the dropdown based on a role in their LDAP profile for example.  In short I'm looking for a separation of concerns around the build and release activities.

Here is what the build looks like, I just want to cherry pick who can actually move the build on at this point of the pipeline.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can use submitter option for this. submitter can be a group or user also you can use multiple group and users.

```
input message: ''Deployment look good?', ok: 'deploy to Production', submitter: 'LDAP_USER_GROUP'
```